# NA replacement using median value

Tags: means, median

I have the following dataset:

```
5   3   3   5   10  10  3   8   2   12  8   6   2   5   6   5   10  4   3   5   4   3   3   5   8   3   5   6   6   1   10  3   6   6   5   8   3   4   3   4   4   3   2.5 1   4   2   2   3   5   10  4   4   6   3   2   3   8   3   4   4   3   3   4   8   4   4   2   4   4   3   2   10  6   3   7   3   5   3   1   4   3   4   3   4   4   2   3   2   4   7   4   6   3.5 3.5 5   3   4   3   5   3   1.5 2.5 3   7   2   5   3   4   2   4   5   3   4   5   4.5 4   6   3   2   1   3   2   2   3   4   6   2   4   2   3   6   1.5 3   3   1   4   3   3   2   3   2   2   6   3   15  1   4   5   2   6   2   4   8   2   8   4   4   4   3   8   4   4   8.5 3   2   7   0.5 3   3   3   2   3   2   4   5   6   2   3.5 3   3   2   2   2.5 2   2   5   2   8   2   4   3   3   2   7   2   4   2   4   4   3   2.5 3   3   3   5 NA NA NA NA NA  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

I want to replace NA's using either Mean or Median value (impute).

Which method would be appropriate in such a case, and why?

Please help me learning.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the dataset, it would be better if you replace NAs by median. Since there are outliers, mean would not be that great idea.